# Stumped by this error: TypeError: 'PCA' object is not callable

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

This error eludes me, because after running type(PCAdata), it returns `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`. After reading about similar "Module" object is not callable errors, it seems to concern not importing the object itself from within the class, such as "from PCA import PCA". However, I'm already importing PCA from sklean.decomposition.

Here is my data: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/wdbc.data

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

#Load CSV
filename = 'data.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(filename)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df=df.dropna(axis=1,how='all')
array = df.values
X = array[:,2:32]
Y = array[:, 1]

#Normalize Data
def normalize(df):
    result = df.copy()
    for feature_name in df.columns:
        max_value = df[feature_name].max()
        min_value = df[feature_name].min()
        result[feature_name] = (df[feature_name] - min_value) / (max_value - min_value)
    return result



df_normalized = normalize(df[ df.columns[2:32]])

pca = PCA(n_components = 16)
pca.fit_transform(df_normalized)
PCAdf = pd.DataFrame(pca.components_, columns = df_normalized.columns, index = ['PC-1','PC-2','PC-3','PC-4','PC-5','PC-6','PC-7','PC-8','PC-9','PC-10','PC-11','PC-12','PC-13','PC-14','PC-15','PC-16'])
PCAarray = PCAdf.values


#Convert all of the "M" class labels as 1, and "B" Labels as 0
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)
df_v_y_encoded = encoder.transform(df_v_y)

#Train again, this time using features from principal component analysis. 
classifierPCAfeatures = svm.SVC(gamma = "auto", C = 1, kernel = "rbf", decision_function_shape='ovo')
classifierPCAfeatures = fit(PCAdf, encoded_Y)
print(classifierPCAfeatures.score(df_v_x, df_v_y_encoded))
```

Comment: `fit = pca.fit(df_normalized)` fit returns **self**, which means the PCA instance `pca`. So, when you try `fit(PCAdf, encoded_Y)` it is like trying `pca(PCAdf, encoded_Y)` , not `pca.fit(PCAdf, encoded_Y)` for example, thus, TypeError: 'PCA' object is not callable.

Comment: @mkaran I just updated my code, and now it returns the error: 'TypeError: 'SelectKBest' object is not callable'. Is this still related?

Comment: It doesn't seem related from what I can see but your code doesn't seem correct. For example, where's the `fit` used in `fit(PCAdf, encoded_Y)` defined now? Did you mean `classifierPCAfeatures.fit(PCAdf, encoded_Y)`?  Where is `df_v_x` defined? Also, in which line does the error occur?